# Getting the name of selected item not value

Tags: php, sql

I have a dropdown menu that is generated in another file, and I would like to echo the name of item they selected from dropdown menu not the value of it (0,1,2,3...).

Here is code of the dropdown menu that is generated in another file:

```
    <?php
        $selectedKey = $_GET['selected_key'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `1 selected` WHERE Key = '".$selectedKey."'";
        $run = mysql_query($query);
        $id1 = 0;
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $run ) ) {
            echo "<option value='".$id1."'>".$row['Contract']."</option>";
        $id1++;
        }
   ?>
```

And this is how it looks in index.php:

```
<select id="text2" name="text2">

</select>
```

Now after they submit data I want to echo the name of the item they selected, but when I use echo `$_REQUEST['text2'];` I get number (value) back, but as said I want to get name.

Comment: When a form is posted, it's the `<option>` that is posted, not the `<select>` so you can't get the name attribute via post data. What are you trying to achieve, maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You can set name you wanted as value , or on submit add hidden field using js and put name in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select box will send only it's selected value index to the server, not the value that you see. So simply use `$row['Contract']` as the value to be sent to the server:

```
echo "<option value='".$row['Contract']."'>".$row['Contract']."</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is browsers do not submit the display text to the server, only the value. There are several workarounds though:

**Option 1**
Set the value as the display text instead of `$id1`. The value does not have to differ from the display text.

**Option 2**
Use a delimeter in the value and set both the value and display text:

```
 echo "<option value='".$id1. ';' . $row['Contract'] ."'>".$row['Contract']."</option>";
```

Explode on the delimiter to get both:

```
list($value, $text) = explode(';', $_POST['text2']);
```

**Option 3**
Use Javascript, set the form's `onsubmit` event to a function that populates a hidden input with the display text.